# IntelliJ plugin unit test with Gradle project import produce: "Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'"

Tags: java, scala, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I'm working on unit tests for our project with Gradle functionality. For correct tests, I need to import the Gradle project and get dependencies from the project. But I'm stuck with this error:

```
Import failed: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
org.gradle.cli.CommandLineArgumentException: Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
```

I was looking for references to this parameter ('--recompile-scripts') in the source code of IntelliJ, but can't find any reference. And this parameter was removed from the Gradle. I can't understand where it appears.

Full stacktrace:

```
Import failed: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
org.gradle.cli.CommandLineArgumentException: Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
at org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser$BeforeFirstSubCommand.onStartOption(CommandLineParser.java:319)
at org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser.parse(CommandLineParser.java:88)
at org.gradle.cli.AbstractCommandLineConverter.convert(AbstractCommandLineConverter.java:22)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderStartParameterConverter.toStartParameter(ProviderStartParameterConverter.java:77)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runClientAction(ProviderConnection.java:151)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:144)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:235)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParametrizedActionRunner.execute(ParametrizedActionRunner.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:63)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:54)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:76)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(GradleExecutionErrorHandler.java:155)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:46)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:178)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:664)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:150)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.JavaGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(JavaGradleProjectResolver.java:94)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:883)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:863)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:141)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:569)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:665)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:574)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


java.lang.AssertionError: Import failed: com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
org.gradle.cli.CommandLineArgumentException: Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
at org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser$BeforeFirstSubCommand.onStartOption(CommandLineParser.java:319)
at org.gradle.cli.CommandLineParser.parse(CommandLineParser.java:88)
at org.gradle.cli.AbstractCommandLineConverter.convert(AbstractCommandLineConverter.java:22)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderStartParameterConverter.toStartParameter(ProviderStartParameterConverter.java:77)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runClientAction(ProviderConnection.java:151)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:144)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:235)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParametrizedActionRunner.execute(ParametrizedActionRunner.java:36)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableActionRunner.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:63)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:54)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:76)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(GradleExecutionErrorHandler.java:155)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:46)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:178)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:664)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:150)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.JavaGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(JavaGradleProjectResolver.java:94)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:883)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:863)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:141)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:76)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:569)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:665)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:574)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at io.snyk.plugin.AbstractGradleTestCase.handleImportFailure(AbstractGradleTestCase.scala:251)
at io.snyk.plugin.AbstractGradleTestCase.doImportProject(AbstractGradleTestCase.scala:240)
at io.snyk.plugin.AbstractGradleTestCase.importProject(AbstractGradleTestCase.scala:179)
at io.snyk.plugin.SnykGradleProjectPluginTest.testGetVulnerabilities(SnykGradleProjectPluginTest.scala:14)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.lambda$runTest$10(UsefulTestCase.java:317)
at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.lambda$invokeTestRunnable$11(UsefulTestCase.java:349)
at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtilKt.runInEdtAndWait(EdtTestUtil.kt:37)
at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.invokeTestRunnable(UsefulTestCase.java:348)
at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.runTest(UsefulTestCase.java:336)
at com.intellij.testFramework.UsefulTestCase.defaultRunBare(UsefulTestCase.java:362)
at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:19)
at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtil$Companion$runInEdtAndWait$1.invoke(EdtTestUtil.kt:14)
at com.intellij.testFramework.EdtTestUtilKt$runInEdtAndWait$2.run(EdtTestUtil.kt:59)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:361)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Source code can be found here

https://github.com/aldanchenko/snyk-intellij-plugin/blob/feat/add-gradle-support/src/test/scala/io/snyk/plugin/SnykGradleProjectPluginTest.scala

https://github.com/aldanchenko/snyk-intellij-plugin/blob/feat/add-gradle-support/src/test/scala/io/snyk/plugin/AbstractGradleTestCase.scala

I really appreciate any help!

Alex.

Comment: did you check the version of the gradle you are using. I think you are using new version of gradle and trying to use a plugin which is not compatible with it

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I checked it. The only solution to this problem is to upgrade the IntelliJ version. Since the previous one used outdated/deprecated Gradle parameters for the tests that caused problems.